# R function to merge columns of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, merge, binary

I have a binary matrix and I want to merge column an and b for example. If there is a 1 and a 0 then the output should be 1. 0 and 0 should stay 0, but 1 and 1 should also stay 1.

```
   a   b    c 
a  1   0    1
b  0   0    0
c  1   1    1
```

so in the end it should look like this

```
   ab  c
a  1   1
b  0   0
c  1   1
```

how can I do that?

I was thinking about the paste function to create a new column but I don't want the output to be 11, 01 , 00 but only one number

Answer (score 0):

Try `(rowSums(df[,c("a","b")])>0)*1`.

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good.   Please consider improving your answer. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Answer (score 0):

Another option using logical operators (though it would be better to convert the data to `logical` first):

```r
data_mat <- matrix(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), nrow = 3)
dimnames(data_mat) <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "c"))

result_mat <- as.data.frame(data_mat)
result_mat[["ab"]] <-
  as.integer(Reduce("|", result_mat[, c("a", "b")]))
result_mat <- as.matrix(result_mat[, c("ab", "c")])
result_mat
#>   ab c
#> a  1 1
#> b  0 0
#> c  1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>